# Gurobi Python: how to write nested sum in a constraint

Tags: python, python-2.7, gurobi

I have an optimization problem and I'm using Python and Gurobi to optimize it. In my problem formulation there is a constraint that has a nested sum.

[constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqDFX.png)

I've recently started learning python and I searched in gurobi documentation and example codes and I couldn't find any example of nested sum.

I was wondering if anyone could help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like for FxT check `sum(a*b for a, b in itertools.product(A, B))` is less than z?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use two for statements inside the `quicksum()` function and two for statements in the generator expression:

```py
mycts = m.addConstrs((quicksum(x[i,f,p]*y[i,f,p,t]
                               for i in I for p in P[i,f]) <= z[f,t]
                               for f in F for t in T), "myconstraint")
```

where m is your `Model` object.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!